# Count matching terms in Lucene 5.0

Tags: java, lucene

I am searching in a field with Lucene_50. I would like to get how many words from my term match the field. For example my field is "JavaServer Faces (JSF) is a Java-based Web application framework intended to simplify development integration of web-based user interfaces.", my query term is "java/jsf/framework/doesnotexist" and want result 3 since only "java", "jsf" and "framework" are present in the field.I want to get how many terms are matched in every doc, Could you tell me whether there are some easy ways to get it in Lucene 5.0 ?

```
    IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(searchField, new IKAnalyzer(true));
    Query query = parser.parse(searchWords);
    TopDocs td = is.search(query, 100000);
    ScoreDoc[] sds = td.scoreDocs;
    for (ScoreDoc sd : sds) {
    Document d = is.doc(sd.doc);
    String postId = d.get(LuceneIndex.idFieldName);
    MemoInfos memoInfos = new MemoInfos();
   String author = d.get(LuceneIndex.memoAuthorFieldName);
   int pId = Integer.parseInt(postId);
   if (map.containsKey(pId)) {                  
      memoInfos.setWeight(map.get(pId).getWeight() + weight);
      map.put(pId, memoInfos);
   } else{
      memoInfos.setWeight(weight);
      map.put(pId, memoInfos);
   }        
   Explanation explanation = is.explain(query, sd.doc);
   System.out.println("explanation------" + explanation.toString());
```

The output with the above mentioned parameters is:

```
    explanation------3.5123634~~~~~~~3.5123634 = (MATCH) product of:
    7.024727 = (MATCH) sum of:
    7.024727 = (MATCH) weight(memoTitle:python in 51533) [], result of:
    7.024727 = score(doc=51533,freq=1.0), product of:
    4.7412157 = queryWeight, product of:
      4.7412157 = idf(docFreq=1936, maxDocs=81643)
      1.0 = queryNorm
    1.4816298 = fieldWeight in 51533, product of:
      1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
      4.7412157 = idf(docFreq=1936, maxDocs=81643)
      0.3125 = fieldNorm(doc=51533)
     0.5 = coord(1/2)
```

I want to get the value of coord, like the 1/2 above

Comment: please clarify you question adding some code.

Comment: Thank you for you reply ! I added more description about my question.